# js not working properly, have some formatting issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying from last couple of hour to make this work but I think there is some issue in my formatting. Sorry I am new to this js. Can anyone suggest any formatting or changes to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

```
// <![CDATA[    
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function(e) {

    j$('.ViewComments').livequery("click",function(e){

    }); 

    /// like 


        j$(document).on('click','a.likethis',function(e){
        var getID   =  j$(this).attr('id').replace('post_id','');               
        j.post("like.php?postId="+getID, {

        }, function(response){
            $( ".templike-"+getID ).empty();
            j$('#like-stats-'+getID).html(response);

            j$('#like-panel-'+getID).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'+getID+'" class="Unlike"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#C00;" ></i></a>');

            //$("#like-loader-"+getID).html('');
        });
    }); 

    /// unlike 


        j$(document).on('click','a.unlike',function(e){
        var getID   =  j$(this).attr('id').replace('post_id','');


        j.post("unlike.php?postId="+getID, {

        }, function(response){
            $( ".templike-"+getID ).empty();
            j$('#like-stats-'+getID).html(response);

            j$('#like-panel-'+getID).html('<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'+getID+'" class="LikeThis"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');

            //$("#like-loader-"+getID).html('');

        });
    }); 



}); 

// ]]>6+
```

I am using this code to increment likes without refreshing the page:

```
 <p class="count-likes" style="margin-right:-3px;" id="container_like"><span id="like-stats-<?php  echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $likes1;?></span>  <span class="templike-<?php  echo $row['id'];?>">Like</span></p> 
              <?php } else { ?>
           <p class="count-likes" style="margin-right:-3px;" id="container_likes"><span id="like-stats-<?php  echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $likes1;?></span>  <span class="templike-<?php  echo $row['id'];?>">Likes</span></p>
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is not working properly

Comment: I am not getting any error. The code just don't work. I have updated my question to show where I am using the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, _"just don't work"_ does not tell anything. What's the _expected_ result? What's the _actual_ result? What's the perceived difference between the two? You'll need to significantly [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38672333/edit) your question to explain these. You might want to check out how to create a [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I already edited the question to SHOW where i am using the code and for what I am using this. I just want to confirm the formatting and do no need to change logic.

Comment: _"I am not getting any error"_ -- there _are_ actual errors in your code which prevent it from running. It is a good idea to open your browser developer console (usually F12) and check the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid name conflicts and declared as var j.

So instead of using it like this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function(e) {});
```

It will be used as (without dollar sign):

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function(e) {});
```

Comment: Also, OP's capitalization is wrong. It's `jQuery` and not `jquery`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did that Thanks. I would like to hight light that If i use "j('.LikeThis').livequery("click",function(e){"   its working perfectly fine but not if I use " j(document).on('click','a.LikeThis',function(e){"

Comment: and when searched on internet, the 2nd method is more appropriate as I am using ajax load more on the same page and after the load more ajax script my   "j('.LikeThis').livequery("click",function(e){"  stops working